# Combining two success runs in parallel

Tags: confidence-interval, binomial-distribution, estimators, reliability, reliability-meta-analysis

The goal is to calculate the reliability of a process. Here reliability is defined as follows:

**Definitions and tests I used**

Let $X$ be a random variable that is equal to $1$ when no defect is present on a fabricated piece and is equal to $0$ when a defect is present. Then, the reliability $R$ of the process is the probability that $X = 1$: $R = \mathbb{P}(X = 1)$.

To compute $R$, I use the Bayesian success run theorem, it says that the $(1-\alpha)$-lower bound $r$ for $R$ after having test $N$ pieces in a row without having detected any defaults is given by:

$$
r = \alpha^\frac{1}{n+1}.
$$

**The problem**

Two tests in parallel are carried out for the same process on different samples: test A and test B to obtain respectively the reliability $R_A$ and $R_B$. Test A respectively test B consists in observing $N_A$ respectively $N_B$ pieces in a row and then applying the success run theorem:

$$
R_A = \alpha^\frac{1}{N_A+1},
$$

and

$$
R_B = \alpha^\frac{1}{N_B+1}.
$$

**The question**
Since these two tests are runned on different samples coming from the same process, can I combined the sample size to obtain the following results for the overall reliability $R$ of the process:

$$
R = \alpha^\frac{1}{N_A + N_B+1}.
$$
Does it make sense to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it does make sense.

The Bayesian success run theorem is based on the assumption that your observations are independent Bernoulli with parameter $p$, where $p$ is the probability that a piece is defect-free. Our prior distribution for $p$ is a $\mathrm{Unif}(0,1)$, which is meant to convey that we have no prior information about the value of $p$.

In this model, examining a sample of $N_A$ pieces then another sample of $N_B$ pieces and finding them all defect-free is the same as examining a sample of $N_A+N_B$ pieces. The lower bound for the reliability is, thus, exactly as you stated it.

The key is that (conditional on $p$) these are independent Bernoulli trials.